# Babel failing on import statement with stage-0 preset

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I'm receiving this error when I attempt to build my app using Webpack and Babel-loader:

```
ERROR in ./src/entry.js
Module parse failed: /home/james/projects/fun-time-phonics/node_modules/babel-loader/index.js!/home/james/projects/fun-time-phonics/src/entry.js Line 1: Unexpected token
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| import React from "react";
| import onReady from "./on-ready";
| import "babel-polyfill";
```

My `.babelrc` looks like this:

```
{
  "presets": ["react", "stage-0"]
}
```

And the relevant webpack loader:

```
{test: ext("js"), exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "babel"}
```

Module versions:

```
"webpack": "^1.12.1",
"babel": "^6.3.26",
"babel-core": "^6.4.0",
"babel-loader": "^6.2.1",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
"babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.3.13",
```

Everything was working fine with Babel 5. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update**:

After adding babel-preset-es2015, my build is now failing on a static class property (despite static properties being added by `babel-preset-stage-0`):

```
ERROR in ./src/components/admin/level-score.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: /home/james/projects/fun-time-phonics/src/components/admin/level-score.js: Missing class properties transform.
  4 | 
  5 | export default class LevelScore extends React.Component {
> 6 |   static defaultProps = {
    |   ^
  7 |     format: "dash"
  8 |   };
  9 | 
    at File.buildCodeFrameError (/home/james/projects/fun-time-phonics/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:408:15)
    at NodePath.buildCodeFrameError (/home/james/projects/fun-time-phonics/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/path/index.js:148:26)
    at pushBody (/home/james/projects/fun-time-phonics/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-classes/lib/vanilla.js:277:20)
    at buildBody (/home/james/projects/fun-time-phonics/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-classes/lib/vanilla.js:244:10)
    at run (/home/james/projects/fun-time-phonics/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-classes/lib/vanilla.js:151:10)
    at PluginPass.ClassExpression (/home/james/projects/fun-time-phonics/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-classes/lib/index.js:63:60)
    at newFn (/home/james/projects/fun-time-phonics/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/visitors.js:276:19)
    at NodePath._call (/home/james/projects/fun-time-phonics/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/path/context.js:74:18)
    at NodePath.call (/home/james/projects/fun-time-phonics/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/path/context.js:46:17)
    at NodePath.visit (/home/james/projects/fun-time-phonics/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/path/context.js:104:12)
    at TraversalContext.visitQueue (/home/james/projects/fun-time-phonics/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/context.js:153:16)
    at TraversalContext.visitSingle (/home/james/projects/fun-time-phonics/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/context.js:113:19)
    at TraversalContext.visit (/home/james/projects/fun-time-phonics/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/context.js:197:19)
    at Function.traverse.node (/home/james/projects/fun-time-phonics/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/index.js:139:17)
    at NodePath.visit (/home/james/projects/fun-time-phonics/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/path/context.js:114:22)
    at TraversalContext.visitQueue (/home/james/projects/fun-time-phonics/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/context.js:153:16)
    at TraversalContext.visitMultiple (/home/james/projects/fun-time-phonics/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/context.js:108:17)
    at TraversalContext.visit (/home/james/projects/fun-time-phonics/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/context.js:195:19)
    at Function.traverse.node (/home/james/projects/fun-time-phonics/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/index.js:139:17)
    at NodePath.visit (/home/james/projects/fun-time-phonics/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/path/context.js:114:22)
    at TraversalContext.visitQueue (/home/james/projects/fun-time-phonics/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/context.js:153:16)
    at TraversalContext.visitQueue (/home/james/projects/fun-time-phonics/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/context.js:159:21)
    at TraversalContext.visitQueue (/home/james/projects/fun-time-phonics/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/context.js:159:21)
    at TraversalContext.visitMultiple (/home/james/projects/fun-time-phonics/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/context.js:108:17)
    at TraversalContext.visit (/home/james/projects/fun-time-phonics/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/context.js:195:19)
    at Function.traverse.node (/home/james/projects/fun-time-phonics/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/index.js:139:17)
    at NodePath.visit (/home/james/projects/fun-time-phonics/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/path/context.js:114:22)
    at TraversalContext.visitQueue (/home/james/projects/fun-time-phonics/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/context.js:153:16)
    at TraversalContext.visitSingle (/home/james/projects/fun-time-phonics/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/context.js:113:19)
    at TraversalContext.visit (/home/james/projects/fun-time-phonics/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/context.js:197:19)
    at Function.traverse.node (/home/james/projects/fun-time-phonics/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/index.js:139:17)
 @ ./src/components/admin/sections/1.js 23:18-43
```

Comment: Try adding `babel-preset-es2015` via `npm install --save-dev babel-preset-es2015`. Then, add `es2015` to your babelrc presets.

Comment: @MarioTacke I added the `es2015` preset alongside `stage-0` and `react`, but now Babel is failing on static class properties.

Comment: Mmmm... Try changing your test inside webpack to `test: /\.jsx?$/, loader...`

Comment: I just realized, in your webpack config, the babel loader is called `babel-loader` not just `babel`.

Comment: @MarioTacke I don't think that makes a difference. I think webpack appends "-loader" if it's not already there.

Comment: @SimpleJ Can you try including **babel-plugin-syntax-class-properties** and **babel-plugin-transform-class-properties** plugins to your project?